# Regex for phone numbers that check if numbers are not the same and last 7 digits are not same

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I am trying to create a regex which matches 7-15 digit number, the number cannot contain all the same digits and Last 7 digits cannot be the same. I have made two regex expressions for number that all numbers cannot be same. The regex which I have made is:

`/^(?!(.)\1+$)^(|[0-9]{7,15})$/`.

And for Last seven digits cannot be same,the regex which i have made is:

`/^(?!.*(\d)\1{6}\b)^[0-9]{0,15}$/`.

But the problem is I am not able to make the regex which full fills both the conditions i.e. all the numbers cannot contain all the same digits and Last 7 digits cannot be the same.

Please suggest how this can be done.

Comment: please make your title shorter...

Comment: Try [`/^(?!(\d)\1+$|\d*(\d)\2{6}$)\d{7,15}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/SD9Eb6/1), or - to also allow an empty string  - `/^(?!(\d)\1+$|\d*(\d)\2{6}$)(?:\d{7,15})?$/`

Comment: Fixed multiple repetitions

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew We need a regex for 10 digits phone number in which 7 digits can't be same in the phone number and all digits cant be same.It should accept only 10 digits phone number.

it should not accept 1111111896 1211111113 1287777777 4444444444.as the regex we are using is /^(?!(\d)\1+$|\d*(\d)\2{6}$)\d{10}$/

Comment: Looks like you need `^(?!(\d)\1+$|\d*(\d)\2{6})(?:\d{7,15})?$` (remove `$` in the lookahead).

Comment: No its working @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: it should not accept 1111111896 1211111113 1287777777 4444444444 @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, try [`^(?!(\d)\1+$|\d*(\d)\2{6})\d{10}$`](https://regex101.com/r/1MBpUW/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use alternation operator inside the negative lookahead to check for 2 conditions:

```
^(?!(\d)\1+$|\d*(\d)\2{6}$)(?:\d{7,15})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SD9Eb6/2).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(\d)\1+$|\d*(\d)\2{6}$)` - the negative lookahead failing the match if all digits are the same from start to end (`(\d)\1+$` where `(\d)` captures a digit into Group 1 and then `\1+` matches one or more values captured in Group 1 followed with end of string check with `$`),  or if only the last 7 are the same (see `\d*(\d)\2{6}$`  where `\d*` matches 0+ digits, `(\d)` captures a digit into Group 2 and then `\2{6}` matches 6 values captured in Group 2 followed with end of string check with `$`)
- `(?:\d{7,15})?` - an optional group matching 7 to 15 digits (or an empty string, as it's optional)
- `$` - end of string.